# plus sign not shown in exponent

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, syntax

I am writing in Latex in the github markdown as shown below.

Why is the plus sign not working in this example?

[image: markov]

```
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=P(X^{t + 1}) \perp P(X^{0:t-1}|P(X^{t})">.
```

I tried this as well

```
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=P(X^{t+1}) \perp P(X^{0:t-1}|P(X^{t})">.
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This question doesn't seem to be about LaTeX and friends.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I find out that `+` can not be decoded so it should be `%2B`. Adding `\!` will make it look better.
So the contents should be `https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=P(X^{t\!%2B\!1}) \perp P(X^{0:t-1}|P(X^{t})`.

And the whole field can be

```xml
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=P(X^{t\!%2B\!1}) \perp P(X^{0:t-1}|P(X^{t})">.
```

[image: Result]